# Correct way to refer to a member function from a static method in a Javascript class

Tags: javascript, class

I have a situation where a class constructor returns the result of calling a static method.

However, in that static method I need to call a function which should be a member function but if it is a member function it is not available.

Is there a good way to do this?

This code should help clarify:

```
class Program {
  constructor (paths) {
    this.inputs = {}
    this.program = Program.createProgram(paths)
    return this.program
  }

  static createProgram () {
      const return_program = {name: test}
      // async function executes
      this.modifyProgramName()  // This is an error because modifyProgram name is not static on this class
      return return_program
 }

 modifyProgramName() {
   // Execute a promise
   fetch('someresource').then(() => {
     this.program.name = 'newName'
   }, 500)
 }
```

Here `modifyProgram` should not really be `static`, because the implication of "modifying" a program is that it already exists.

However, when I want to call `modifyProgram` in `createProgram` which is essentially the constructor, I can't because no instance of the Program class exists yet.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Why is `createProgram()` static? Assuming you get past the current issue, how would you use the above class?

Comment: `createProgram` is static because it is called in the constructor to return a program. You couldn't call it in the constructor if it weren't static.

Comment: You should still be able to call a method from the constructor. I'll update my answer to show you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `this` to the static function. Like this:

```
class Program {
  constructor (paths) {
    this.inputs = {}
    this.program = Program.createProgram(paths, this)
    return this
  }

  static createProgram (paths, program) {
      const return_program = {name: "test"}
      // async function executes
      program.modifyProgramName()  // This is an error because modifyProgram name is not static on this class
      return return_program
   }
  modifyProgramName() {
     setTimeout(() => {
       this.program.name = 'newName'
     }, 500)
  }
}
```

Results from the console:

```
pgm = new Program(["/one"]);
Program {inputs: Object, program: Object}
pgm.program.name
"newName"
```

Note that I changed your `setTimeout` to use the `=>` format so that `this` will be the one from the object.

If you don't need `createProgram` to be static, then this will work:

```
class Program {
  constructor (paths) {
    this.inputs = {}
    this.program = this.createProgram(paths)
    return this
  }

  createProgram (paths) {
      const return_program = {name: "test"}
      // async function executes
      this.modifyProgramName()  // This is an error because modifyProgram name is not static on this class
      return return_program
   }
  modifyProgramName() {
     setTimeout(() => {
       this.program.name = 'newName'
     }, 500)
  }
}

pgm = new Program(["/one"]);
Program {inputs: Object, program: Object}
pgm.program.name
"newName"
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a bad idea to return something other than 'this' inside a constructor as this may break inheritance.

In any case, the problem is that when the setTimeout is passed a function using the function keyword, it executes in the global context which means the 'this' keyword will be pointing to the global scope. One way of dealing with that would be to use the es6 fat arrow functions or to use the 'bind' keyword.

```
(function() {
  this.program.name = 'newName';
}).bind(this)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uvwt9eqd/1/

Comment: I am not entirely sure if this changes things but I used `setTimeout` as a simple demo.  In actuality a web request is made.  Question updated

Comment: nope doesn't change anything. Either use an arrow function as @Steve has suggested or bind the function

Comment: *"In any case, the problem is"* - This isn't "the" problem, it's a secondary problem that won't occur until the code is changed somehow to allow `modifyProgramName()` to be called in the first place.